# how to change http:mydomainname.com/inner-page.php?articleid=10 To http:mydomainname.com/inner-page.php/Title

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to change  http:mydomainname.com/inner-page.php?articleid=10 To http:mydomainname.com/inner-page.php?articleid=Title
 please give me a easy way i have also tried Apache mod_rewrite.

but my confusion is that how to .htaccess file know my title by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with mod_rewrite or Apache alone, because there is no way Apache or mod_rewrite know how to translate from `"10"` to `"Title"`. You'll most likely want to do this with a database lookup, and you are better off doing this in your `inner-page.php`.

```
if( isset( $_GET['articleid'] ) ) {
  $title = database_lookup_function( $_GET['articleid'] );
  header( '302 Moved Temporarily' );
  header( "location: /inner-page.php?articletitle=$title" );
  exit();
}
```

Or if you really want to keep the same variable thorough your entire script, which sounds silly:

```
if( isset( $_GET['articleid'] ) && intval( $_GET['articleid'], 10 ) == $_GET['articleid'] ) {
  $title = database_lookup_function( $_GET['articleid'] );
  header( '302 Moved Temporarily' );
  header( "location: /inner-page.php?articleid=$title" );
  exit();
}
```

---

To load `inner-page.php?category=radiono&lanug=India&articleid=sarukh-khan-performs-a-na‌​tural-language` when `inner-page.php/radiono/India/sarukh-khan-performs-a-natural-language` is requested, use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^inner-page\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /inner-page.php?category=$1&lanug=$2&articleid=$3 [L]
```

Comment: sounds like i am needed to be  pass title in my url in place of id  than rewrite my URL by .ht-access  ? is the only way

Comment: You can only rewrite what is already in the url, so if your script works with the title and the title is already in the url, then: yes, you can do that, and that is the only way I am aware of.

Comment: now i change my url to "inner-page.php?category=radiono&lanug=India&articleid=sarukh-khan-performs-a-natural-language" how to change it in "inner-page.php/radiono/India/sarukh-khan-performs-a-natural-language" by ht-access

Comment: can you please give me idea of code i needed in my .ht-access file to do that this is first time i touch the mod_rewrite  i have no idea how to achieve  "inner-page.php/radiono/India/sarukh-khan-performs-a-natural-language"  by .ht-access