# how to replace id with associated db title in url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

[ Related question: [How to write htaccess rewrite rule for seo friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url) ]

I need to replace section id with associated title name in database .

```
example.com/section.php?id=5
```

change to

```
example.com/section/travel
```

where id 5 has title travel in database

is it possible using htaccess?
if yes how would htaccess look like.

thanks.

Comment: Are you using a web framework or rolling your own?

Comment: Is `section.php` able to find a row by its title instead of its id ?

Comment: If you are rolling on your own, you may try something like https://github.com/chriso/klein.php

Comment: my own that's why i need to to it and need to learn with . with getting some help here

Comment: justin . no am just using id unique and as primary key in other tables. 

but example.com/section.php?id=Travel change to example.com/section/Travel . would also help

Comment: how your `header("location:")` part looks like?

Comment: Adarsh hota . . sorry i dont understand what do you mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change http:mydomainname.com/inner-page.php?articleid=10 To http:mydomainname.com/inner-page.php/Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063009/how-to-change-httpmydomainname-com-inner-page-phparticleid-10-to-httpmydomain)

Comment: (or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473705/how-to-redirect-to-dynamic-content-with-htaccess/24474616#24474616)